# how to add Authorization header by using open api swagger doc

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to add Authorization header in the api call and could you please tell how to configure by using open api swagger doc.

code :

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application-description}") String appDesciption, @Value("${application-version}") String appVersion) {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                    .title("Access Management APIs")
                    .version("1.0")
                    .description("Access Management APIs for tp db")
                    .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
                    .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")));
}
```

controller class:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{aNumber}",
            produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateSubsidyAward(@Valid @RequestBody UpdateAwardDetailsRequest awardUpdateRequest,
                                                 @PathVariable("aNumber") Long aNumber) 
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***OpenApiConfig***

```
package com.user.demoapp.config;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Contact;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components())
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("App_name")
                        .description("App_description")
                        .version("0.0.1")
                        .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
                        .contact(new Contact().name("contact_name").email("contact_email_address"))
                        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org"))


                );
    }
}
```

***Controller class***

```
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "*")
@Tag(name = "api_title", description = "api_description")
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Operation(summary = "api_summary ", description = "api_description", tags = { "api_Tag" })
    @PostMapping(path = "/test-api")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponseDTO> addTest(@RequestBody List<testDTO> testModel) {
        return testService.addtest(testModel);
    }
}
```

I hope you found what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. i will try and will let you know if any issues

Comment: i hv used @CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "Authhorization,UserPrinciple") in the controller and restarted my spring boot application but still i am not able to see any option in the swagger to enter the Authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

Add components(new Components()
.addSecuritySchemes())

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application-description}") String appDesciption, @Value("${application-version}") String appVersion) {

    final String securitySchemeName = "basicAuth";

        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName, new SecurityScheme()
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                .scheme("basic"))
                )
                .info(new Info()
                    .title("Access Management APIs")
                    .version("1.0")
                    .description("Access Management APIs for tp db")
                    .termsOfService("http://swagger.io/terms/")
                    .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org")));
}
```